# JPA integration with maven - Which provider is being used when the dependency is added?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, querydsl

I've been experimenting with JPA and QueryDSL. I cannot simply include QueryDSL in my POM.xml, when using maven.

I also need to include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is, since JPA is only a specification, which provider is being used here? Is it SpringData, is it Hibernate? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: None... Only adding the api is going to do nothing.

Comment: You need to use the implementation of the JPA, hibernate, toplink,.if you are using spring boot, just with the dependency spring-boot-starter-data-jpa everything is included. Execute mvn tree dependecy to check which libraries are added

Comment: @cralfaro Spring Boot uses Hibernate by default.

Comment: @simas_ch yeap, but is everything included in the parent dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" so you have JAP and implementation at same time, no need to include anything else

Comment: why would you start experimenting with JPA and use v1.0? You should use v2.1 even though that is old in itself

Comment: then this only works with a shared 2nd level cache.

Comment: Okay, cool, I'll use v2.1. And thanks for the replies. I guess I'll add Hibernate as a dependency in my pom.xml as well.